# Resize function resize does't trigger when need it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can't make it working.

- if window is > 800 should have 6 images red background
- if window is < 800 should have 4 images blue background

Should work on resize and on load. What am I missing?

```
    var $container = $(container);

    $(window).on("resize", function () {
        $('.items > .item', $container).each(function (i) {

            if ($(window).width() > 800) {
                if (i % 6 == 0) {
                    $(this).nextAll().andSelf().slice(0, 6).wrapAll('<div class="wrap fadeIn"></div>');
                }
                $(".grid-container").removeClass('four');
                $(".grid-container").addClass('six');
            }

            if ($(window).width() < 800) {
                if (i % 4 == 0) {
                    $(this).nextAll().andSelf().slice(0, 4).wrapAll('<div class="wrap fadeIn"></div>');
                }
                $(".grid-container").removeClass('six');
                $(".grid-container").addClass('four');
            }
        })
    }).trigger('resize');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mE8br/

Comment: `.andSelf` is deprecated, use `.addBack()`

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon thanks but still it doesn't work as wanted. Not sure why doesn't change on fly when resizing the page

Comment: Just as a suggestion, you should move the check for window width outside of the each function. This way it only checks once per resize call instead of every time per item per resize call. Also I am not sure why you re triggering resize at the end. If you need this code to run right away then put it in a function and call it on doc ready

Comment: Any error in the console? F12

Comment: @Huangism  http://jsfiddle.net/Ejek6/1/ thanks, but still no luck, also is giving me an error now! could u please double check?

Comment: it's not working because you defined resize inside of slide function

Comment: @Huangism cool thanks, right now I got it like u said, could u check it please?http://jsfiddle.net/Ejek6/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added an overall div to make it easier to target the items

http://jsfiddle.net/Ejek6/4/

You had

```
'.items > .item'
```

I changed it to

```
'.items .item'
```

Since you are wrapping item with a div the > selector no longer works

If you want your code to be the same as you wrote it then http://jsfiddle.net/Ejek6/5/
I only updated the selector

In this version I moved the check for window width out so it is more efficient

http://jsfiddle.net/Ejek6/6/

Comment: thank you so much! I was stuck!!!! I just want a good code, not sure mine is good enough. what do u think?

Comment: the last fiddle is your code except I mvoed the check for window width out. It's fine for now, good code come from experience. No need to hurry

Comment: thanks dude but could u inspect the the html? it multiplies all the divs <div class="wrap fadeIn"> so like that wont work!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ejek6/8/ this one is how should be, but with all this <div class="wrap fadeIn"> is not going to work. could u double check please?

Comment: if u check the latest fiddle u can see it, basically its a slider, its animating horizontally

Comment: I think I understand, you should post this as a different question. I don't know how to fix this right now and work is getting busy. Posting a new question will attract more people. You can provide the latest fiddle to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: hey dude, would u be able to help me with this as I'm stuck?

Comment: Also while your original wraps the li, this creates invalid html as divs are wrapping li tags. Post the wrapping issue as a different question now that resize is working

Comment: cool dude, u right! thanks for that! I'm putting a new question now.

Answer (score 0):

The first time through, this matches a number of items:

```
$('.items > .item', $container)
```

However, the first run alters your DOM so that this no longer matches anything.  You wrap your items in `div` elements so `.items` no longer has any direct `.item` children.

Your handler fire but loops over nothing.

Comment: oh, thanks for spotting it! nice one. have u got a solution? as I'm bloody stuck with this